# CFL Intersection with Regular Language prove

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

how can i prove the following statement :

1- $L_1\subseteq\Sigma^*$ is CFL and $L_2\subseteq\Sigma^*$ is regular Language, then $L_1$\ $L_2$ is CFL .

so i want to know what is the method to prove it ?

I'm not sure, but can i use a PDA and DFA or something else ?

---

so i tried the following :

$L_2$ is regular and thus is $\overline{\rm  L_2}$ also regular.

$L_1 \cap \overline{\rm  L_2}$ is CFL $\iff$ $L_1 \cap \overline{\rm  L_2}$ is recognized by a PDA.

$M1=(Z_1,\Sigma,\Gamma,\delta_1,z_{01},$#$,E_1)$ is a PDA for $L_1$

$M_2=(Z_1,\Sigma,\delta_2,z_{02},E_2)$ is a DFA for $\overline{\rm  L_2}$

$M^{'}$=($Z_1$x$Z_2$,$\Sigma,\Gamma,\delta^{''},(z_{01},z_{02}),$#$,E_1$x$E_2)$
, so that $M^{'}$=$M_1\cap M_2$

but how should i define $\delta{'' ?}$

Many Thanks

Comment: What closure properties do you know? Intersection of a CFL and a regular language?

Comment: from what i studied i know that CFLs are closed under the following properties :
the union
the concatenation
the Kleene star
 but not under Intersection

Comment: but for a CFL and a regular language i don't know any

Comment: I suggest spending some more time with this question. It is within your capabilities.

Comment: i was able to conclude that $L_1$ \ $L_2$ = $L_1 \cap \overline{\rm  L_2}$ is this correct  , but still i can't understand exacly how to start i have been trying since yesterday

Comment: Oops – sorry for deceiving your. I misread Hendrik's comment for your answer to his comment. One of the closure properties of context-free languages you were supposed to know is closure under intersection with a regular language. This can be proved either using the product construction (like what you were trying), or by modifying a context-free grammar (like in the construction of a CFG equivalent to a given PDA).

Comment: Closure under intersection with a regular language is classic, and should be found in any decent textbook. For the grammar construction, see [lecture notes of Checkoway](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~s/teaching/cs271/2014-spring/cfl-regular.pdf). The PDA construction can be found in [these slides](http://www.math.uni-heidelberg.de/logic/ss17/formsprach/fs09-cf-closure-properties-41.pdf).